# sytnax help PHP

Tags: php, html

how to write this synax correctly, here just i want to make target link for profile...

```
<a href="index.php?p=profile&uid=$_SESSION["uid"]"> $_SESSION["username"]</a>
```

my variables are:

```
$_SESSION["uid"] ="32"; 
$_SESSION["username"] = "metaxa";
```

I want to add `$_SESSION["uid"]` after `&uid=` ,

and i want to add  `$_SESSION["username"]` between `<a></a>` tags

Comment: Please have a look at [Escaping from HTML](http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phpmode.php). You can also check the [strings reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php).

Comment: <a href="index.php?p=profile&uid=<?php echo $_SESSION['uid']; ?>"> <?php echo $_SESSION["username"]; ?></a>

Answer (score 1):

```
<a href="index.php?p=profile&uid=<?php echo $_SESSION['uid'] ?>"> echo $_SESSION['username']</a>
```

Comment: You should add an explanation for why this solves the problem, a code block by itself with no context isn't very useful for other users coming here looking for help.

Answer (score 1):

You want something like:

```
<a href="index.php?p=profile&uid=<?php echo $_SESSION['uid']; ?>"> <?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like that:

```
$link = sprintf(
    '<a href="index.php?p=profile&uid=%s">%s</a>',
    $_SESSION["uid"] ="32",
    $_SESSION["username"] = "metaxa"
);

echo $link;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either enter PHP mode and use `echo` or `printf` to print the text, or you can use shorthand `<?= ... ?>` syntax for the same effect.

```
<a href="index.php?p=profile&uid=<?= $_SESSION["uid"] ?>"><?= $_SESSION["username"] ?></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php if (@$_SESSION["activeuser"]) { ?>
            <a href="index.php?p=profile&uid=<?php echo $_SESSION['userid']; ?>"> <?php echo $_SESSION["username"]; ?></a>

        <?php}
        else { ?>
        <a href="index.php?p=login">Login</a> &nbsp;  / &nbsp; <a href="index.php?p=joinus">Join us</a>
         <?php } ?> </div>     

Now the link is working, but else part of the `if` is working also
```

Comment: I logged in and i have active $_SESSION["activeuser"], but on the login/register div shows the name of user and login/register buttons..

Answer (score 0):

You can `echo` with double quotes, escape inline double quote and use curly braces + single quotes to access array elements.

```
echo "<a href=\"index.php?p=profile&uid={$_SESSION['uid']}\">{$_SESSION['username']}</a>";
```